# How to get a variable from a different class?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a class named `TerminalPanel` which has the following method:

```
def OnSerialRead(self, event):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    text = event.data
```

Now, I want to get the value of `text` from another method (`get_data`) in another class (`GraphicsPanel`).

How do I get this value?  I tried `marito = TerminalPanel.OnserialRead.text`, but I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'text'`

---

## Update

I have set-up the `TerminalPanel` class to include the variable `text` as part of it:

```
def OnSerialRead(self, event):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    self.text = event.data
```

But now when I call it like this: `marito = TerminalPanel.text` inside my `GraphicsPanel` class I get the following error:

> AttributeError: type object 'TerminalPanel' has no attribute 'text'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: call text on the instance not the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is a lack of context and confusion what actually to do. I suppose you try to rework the `wxTerminal.py` from `pyserial`. I have to admit this part of pyserial is neither very readable (has been created by wxGlade) nor is it easy to understand (requires understanding of the wxPython event system and spinning off of threads (to keep the GUI responsive when reading on the serial port).

However, according to your problem description, it seems to me you want to do the following:

Get the value of `event.text` when it arrives and process it further in your `GraphicsPanel` instance.

You have to possibilities:

1) Bind to the event:

In your `GraphicsPanel` class:

```
class GraphicsPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.parent = self.GetParent() # this should result in a wx.Frame instance!
        # binding on wx.Frame required, because wx.Panel will not catch the event
        self.parent.Bind(EVT_SERIALRX, self.OnSerialRead)

    def OnSerialRead(self, event):
        text = event.text
        ...
        event.Skip() # important: you have to skip it also in ``TerminalPanel`` if you
        # want to bind twice
```

2) Call the routine in `GraphicsPanel` instance with `event.text` as argument.

```
class TerminalPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self._grphpnl = GraphicsPanel(...)
        self.Bind(EVT_SERIALRX, self.OnSerialRead)

    def OnSerialRead(self, event):
        text = event.text
        # do something with it in GraphicsPanel instance
        self._grphpnl.OnSerialText(text)
        ...
```

Somewhere else in your code:

```
class GraphicsPanel(wx.Panel):
    ...
    def OnSerialText(text):
        # do something with the text
```

Comment: Thanks! you seem to get what I was trying to do hehehe.  Which option is more correct?

Comment: Both are "correct", in a sense that they will work. -Version 1): you have to understand how to work (double-binding, Skip) with events. +Version 1): Clear separation of scope, decoupling. - Version 2): You have to keep a reference to another panel (GraphicsPanel) + Version 2): No deeper understanding of double-binding required

Comment: Ok, seems #2 is my huckleberry

Comment: I've been playing with both options.  Option #2 gets me an extra small window on the left top corner.  Option #1 doesn't seem to work at all :(

Comment: With the ``wx.lib.inspection`` toolkit you can highlight that frame/control and find out what it is. Did you create ``GraphicsPanel`` twice -> do you have more than one line with ``... = GraphicsPanel(...)``?

Comment: Yes, I have a `TopPanel` class that creates both the `self.terminal_panel = TerminalPanel(self)` and the `self.graphics_panel = GraphicsPanel(self)`.  I tried calling it through the entire address: `self._grphpnl = MainWindow.top_panel.graphics_panel(self)` but it gives me an error about the object not having that attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65529/discussion-between-nepix32-and-mario-s-e).

Answer (score 1):

That variable is defined at function scope. There is no way to get that value.

To make the value available to anything outside of the method you need to store the value on the class `self.text = event.data` or return the value `return text`

You need to decide what is right for the situation though, I'm guessing by the name of the function that returning the data is the right thing to do.

Comment: How do I get the value?

Comment: self.text will get the value, note return text won't work as the binding calls the handler function when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value!

```
def OnSerialRead(self, event):
    """Handle input from the serial port."""
    text = event.data
    return text
```

Then you can access the value like this

```
marito = TerminalPanel.OnserialRead(event)
```

Or save the value in the class:

```
class Reader():
    def OnSerialRead(...):
        ...
        self.text = event.data
```

and then access the value from the class like so:

```
marito = Reader.text
```

Comment: I got this: `TypeError: unbound method OnSerialRead() must be called with TerminalPanel instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Comment: @MarioS.E. Sorry! Forgot to add that you need to send the event along.

Comment: @MarioS.E. But Im starting to feel that the method is only being called when a event occurs? Then the second approach may be more aproptiate.

Comment: How do I send it? I'm sorry, I'm terribly new at this.  Do I go `TerminalPanel(self).OnSerialRead()`

Comment: @MarioS.E. Like you would any argument to a method. Method( someValue )

Comment: If I go with option #1, i.e., with `return` I get this error: `NameError: global name 'event' is not defined`.  If I go with option #2 I get `AttributeError: type object 'TerminalPanel' has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @MarioS.E. Then I suggest that you start reading up on python class construcion.